# Condition for integral in contour to tend to zero

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

Consider a square centered at $(0,0)$ of side length $2x_1$ and the contour $\gamma_{x_1}$ consisting of the upper half of this square oriented counterclockwise. This is a contour that often appears in complex integration.

Inspired by [these great notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejorloff/18.04/notes/topic9.pdf), I wanted to find a sufficient condition for a function so that its integral on the path $\gamma_{x_1}$ tends to zero as $x_1\to +\infty$. This is my attempt:

*Consider a continuous function $f$ such that for every $z\in \gamma_{x_1}$ we have
$$|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^a},$$
where $M>0$ and $a>0$. Then,
$$\int_{\gamma_{x_1}}f(z)e^{ibz}dz\xrightarrow{x_1\to+\infty}0,$$
for every $b>0$.*

**Proof:**
Notice that
\begin{align*}\big|f(z)e^{ibz}\big|\leq M\frac{\big|e^{ibz}\big|}{|z|^a}=M\frac{e^{-b\text{Im} z}}{|z|^a}\leq M\frac{e^{-bx_1}}{x_1^a},\end{align*}
for $z\in \gamma_{x_1}$.
Therefore, we can bound the integral as follows:
\begin{align*}\left|\int_{\gamma_{x_1}}f(z)e^{ibz}dz\right|&\leq \text{length}(\gamma_{x_1})\max_{z\in \gamma_{x_1}}\big|f(z)e^{ibz}\big|\\
&\leq 4x_1M\frac{e^{-bx_1}}{x_1^a}.\end{align*}
Now, the last expression tends to $0$ as $x_1\to +\infty$ since the exponential goes faster to zero. Done.

**Is my proposition correct? Thanks!**

**EDIT:** As @FShrike commented, the bound $e^{-b\text{Im}z}\leq e^{-bx_1}$ is not correct. So we must assume $a>1$ rather than $a>0$ so that the correct integral bound
$$\left|\int_{\gamma_{x_1}}f(z)e^{ibz}dz\right|\leq \frac{4M}{x_1^{a-1}},$$
tends to zero when $x_1\to +\infty$.

Comment: The imaginary part is always $\ge0$ so $e^{-b\Im z}\le e^0=1$. Your bound is not correct, I don't think

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @FShrike! I updated the question and I think now everything is correct.